# Convention for mapping collections to scalars via LINQ in Automapper

Tags: .net, automapper, automapper-2

Automapper already does some nice convention stuff like mapping sub-properties by naming convention e.g. `OrderTotal` would map from `Order.Total` if such a property on a property existed.

I was wondering if there is a way to do a similar thing with LINQ operator names. For example if I had a collection `IEnumerable<Appointment>` called `Appointments`, it would be great if on my target type I had a property called `AppointmentFirst` of type Appointment and AutoMapper automagically called `First()`.

Is there any way to do something like this currently?

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for such things out of the box. However you can achieve it by using [custom type converters.](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters)